# Pull nuxt 3 module configuration

Tags: module, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-module

### How to fetch module config?

I am in the process of creating a module for nuxt3. How do I pull information from the module config to component file?

```js
export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({     //module.ts file
  meta: {
    name: 'photoGallery',
    configKey: 'photoGallery',
    compatibility: {
      nuxt: '^3.0.0'
    }
  },
  defaults: {
    rowNumbers: 4,
  },
}
```